# Swift - UISwitch not updating when toggled On/Off

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiswitch, addtarget

I am trying to create a UISwitch programatically (No IBOutlets or IBActions) and I can't seem to figure out how to get the switch to change states when pressed. I thought that ...

```
mySwitch.addTarget()
```

... would be called every time the switch was toggled On/Off, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong and how to correct this.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320 * 0.75, height: 568 * 0.75))

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
view.layer.borderWidth = 1

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320 * 0.75, height: 50))

label.text = "Label"
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

view.addSubview(label)

func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch!) {
    if sender.on == true {
        label.text = "Switch is ON"
    } else if sender.on == false {
        label.text = "Switch is OFF"
    }
}

let mySwitch = UISwitch()

mySwitch.center = view.center
mySwitch.setOn(true, animated: false)
mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
mySwitch.addTarget(label, action: Selector(switchChanged(mySwitch)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

view.addSubview(mySwitch)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some fixes for this line:

```
mySwitch.addTarget(label, action: Selector(switchChanged(mySwitch)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

To make `addTarget` to work, you need an instance which responds to the action. Obviously `label` would not respond to `switchChanged`.

Enclose your action method in a class:

```
class MyTarget {
    @objc func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch!) {
        if sender.on == true {
            label.text = "Switch is ON"
        } else if sender.on == false {
            label.text = "Switch is OFF"
        }
    }
}
```

Another problem is the usage of `Selector.init`, if you write `Selector(switchChanged(mySwitch))`, Swift executes the argument `switchChanged(mySwitch)`, and then passes the result to `Selector.init`.
While the return type of `switchChanged` is `Void`, your code is nearly the same as writing `Selector()`.

Try using `#selector` notation as far as possible. In this case, with the class introduced above, you can write it as `#selector(MyTarget.switchChanged)`.

So, to `addTarget` properly, you need to change the line as:

```
let target = MyTarget()
mySwitch.addTarget(target, action: #selector(MyTarget.switchChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

My Xcode is sort of stubborn and I needed to restart Xcode to see the liveview timeline, but, with these changes, I believe your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
mySwitch.addTarget(label, action: Selector(switchChanged(mySwitch)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

But it is not the label that contains the `switchChanged` function: it's *you*.

You'll have much better luck configuring this properly in an actual app project (i.e. not a playground). You'll have a view controller that can act as `self` and can be the target.

Comment: Don't try to play with serious interaction like this in a playground. It's like kissing a frog: nothing happens and it annoys the frog.